# setting of Username and Password for solr 5.2 standalone core setup

Tags: solr

Changes in  -  /example/etc/webdefault.xml

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Solr authenticated application</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
      <role-name>core1-role</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>

  <login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Test Realm</realm-name>
  </login-config>
```

modify jetty.xml file as well from /example/etc/jetty.xml

```
<Call name="addBean">
      <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.security.HashLoginService">
          <Set name="name">Test Realm</Set>
          <Set name="config"><SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
          <Set name="refreshInterval">0</Set>
        </New>
      </Arg>
    </Call>
```

I have changed as per the suggestions for authentication in solr. A dialog box appears to enter username and password in it. Even though entering correct username and password, it doesn't takes me to the solr home screen. Am I doing anything wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed the  absolute path to relative path into

```
<SystemProperty name="jetty.home" default="."/>/etc/realm.properties</Set>
```

solved my problem!

Comment: The absolute path is put into what configuration file?